# How to use MultithreadedMapper in Spring Batch?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, spring-data, spring-batch

I tried to use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper` with Spring Batch and Spring Hadoop in local.

The hadoop job runs with `org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobExecutor` and `SyncTaskExecutor`. 
Is there a way to map with `MultithreadedMapper` in spring batch?

Comment: are you following http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/batch-wordcount.html ? seems you should not use the mapper without a special hadoop tasklet